# How do I format a post's date using shortcodes in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, date-formatting

Can anybody help with this please? I'm using this shortcode to display a post's date below the title [mm-insert-date]  It works fine, but is displaying as "2014-02-01 01:24:27"  I would like it to read something like "Feb 2 2014" and lose the clock time. I've tried quite a few things from searching etc but nothing's working for me.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Here's the function from the themes function.php file

```
function mm_insert_date_func($atts) {
   // Insert the post date, with optional before and after strings.
   // [mm-insert-date before='<h3>' after='</h3>']
   global $post;
   extract(shortcode_atts(array('before' => '', 'after' => '' ), $atts));  

   $output = "{$before}{$post->post_date}{$after}";      


   return $output;
}

add_shortcode('mm-insert-date', 'mm_insert_date_func');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution that works:

```
$output = $before . date('M j Y', strtotime($post->post_date)) . $after;
```